# Php upload form userinput = filename

Tags: php

Ok building a php webform need one of the entries to be the filename written.

How can I achieve this?

Here's my php code...

```
$filename = "output.txt"; #Must CHMOD to 666
$text = $_POST['bin'];
$text2 = $_POST['pcn'];
$text3 = $_POST['gnum'];
$text4 = $_POST['memid'];
$text5 = $_POST['urlen'];
$text6 = $_POST['urles'];
$text7 = $_POST['tlogo'];

 # Form must use POST. if it uses GET, use the line below:
#$text = $_GET['theformfieldname']; #POST is the preferred method

$fp = fopen ($filename, "w"); # w = write to the file only, create file if it does not exist, discard existing contents
if ($fp) {
fwrite ($fp, "$text\r\n");
fwrite ($fp, "$text2\r\n");
fwrite ($fp, "$text3\r\n");
fwrite ($fp, "$text4\r\n");
fwrite ($fp, "$text5\r\n");
fwrite ($fp, "$text6\r\n");
fwrite ($fp, "$text7\r\n");
fclose ($fp);

header("Location: logo.html"); 
}
else {
echo ("There was an error please submit your request again");
}

?>
```

ok need $filename = "output.txt";
to be from the input $text3 = $_POST['gnum'];

something along the lines of:

$filename = $_POST['gnum'].txt; 
but this wont work..

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
$filename = $_POST['gnum'].txt;
```

you should use

```
$filename = $_POST['gnum'].".txt";
```

Comment: fixed ;) I did miss the '.' in the '.txt', i did!

Comment: Warning: fopen(rxc45632.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/test/form/welcome.php on line 15
There was an error please submit your request again

Comment: you don't have permission to open that file, like it said. Fix you filepermissions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not **super** clear on what you're asking, but I think you want to know how to appent '.txt' to the end of the $_GET variable?

If that's the case, you just need to do this:

```
$text3 = $_POST['gnum'] . '.txt';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for getting the file name.

```
$_FILES["file"]["name"]
```